# Insert js variable into OpenStreetMap element (coordinates)

Tags: javascript, html, openstreetmap

I want to create a OpenstreatMap with a polygon in it. The coordinates of the polygon are fetched from databank(via ajax). Finally the coordinates are stored in an variable (js) and i want to use the variable as "input data" for the polygon.

The following example works perfect. (given example).

Thank you for your help!

```
//this part of the code works
var map_xy = L.map(name_map_EEG).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13); L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
    {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map_xy);
    var polygon = L.polygon([
    [51.5010, -0.08],
    [51.504, -0.06],
    [51.513, -0.047]
    ])
    polygon.addTo(map_xy);



//Input data looks like this => var coordinates = [51.5010, -0.08],[51.504, -0.06],[51.513, //-0.047]
                        var polygon = L.polygon(coordinates);
                        polygon.addTo(map_xy);

//I want to insert the data from coordinates, it does not work.
```